# opencl giving different results on different nvidia drivers?

Tags: opencl

This is a sample problem to understand the functioning of OpenCl.

**Problem**: I have three arrays **array1, array2, array3**. addition of each element of an array2 and array3 is saved into array1.

**example: array1[1] = array2[1] + array3[1];**

array1, array2 and array3 is a global double array in a c program. these arrays are initialized with value 1.0;

then these arrays are passed to GPU using opencl in buffer. In opencl code, i am using 10 workitems, hence, each workitem is dealing with each element of these arrays by calling the desired function. and updating the buffer. Updated buffer is read back with updated values of array1, array2 and array3 arrays.

updated value of array1 is passed to array2 and array3 and again kernel is called. to evaluate again.

Hence result should come:

```
loading kernel..
kernel loaded..
Step 0..
array1[0] = 2.000000
array1[1] = 2.000000
array1[2] = 2.000000
array1[3] = 2.000000
array1[4] = 2.000000
array1[5] = 2.000000
array1[6] = 2.000000
array1[7] = 2.000000
array1[8] = 2.000000
array1[9] = 2.000000
....
....
....
Step 10..
array1[0] = 18.000000
array1[1] = 18.000000
array1[2] = 18.000000
array1[3] = 18.000000
array1[4] = 18.000000
array1[5] = 18.000000
array1[6] = 18.000000
array1[7] = 18.000000
array1[8] = 18.000000
array1[9] = 18.000000
```

which is coming **fine for nVidia Corporation GeForce GT 630 (rev a1) graphics card with driver version: 331.49**

But if i am running the same code in **nVidia Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1) graphics card with driver version: 260.19.26**. Then results are wrong. Infact values are not even changing for array1

```
loading kernel..
kernel loaded..
Step 0..
array1[0] = 1.000000
array1[1] = 1.000000
array1[2] = 1.000000
array1[3] = 1.000000
array1[4] = 1.000000
array1[5] = 1.000000
array1[6] = 1.000000
array1[7] = 1.000000
array1[8] = 1.000000
array1[9] = 1.000000
....
....
....
Step 10..
array1[0] = 1.000000
array1[1] = 1.000000
array1[2] = 1.000000
array1[3] = 1.000000
array1[4] = 1.000000
array1[5] = 1.000000
array1[6] = 1.000000
array1[7] = 1.000000
array1[8] = 1.000000
array1[9] = 1.000000
```

Why different results on different graphics card?

running.c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)

cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
cl_context context = NULL;
cl_command_queue command_queue = NULL;
cl_program program = NULL;
cl_kernel kernel = NULL;
cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
cl_uint ret_num_devices;
cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
cl_int ret;
cl_event event;
size_t source_size;
cl_mem array1Buffer, array2Buffer, array3Buffer;
size_t global_work_size[1] = {5};

#define size 10
double array1[size];
double array2[size];
double array3[size];


void create () {
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    fp = fopen("calc.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);


    /*Initialization*/
    /* Get Platform and Device Info */
    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    /* Create OpenCL context */
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    /* Create Command Queue */
    command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    /*Initialization complete*/

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i< size ; i++) {
        array1[i] = 1.0;
        array2[i] = 1.0;
        array3[i] = 1.0;
    }

    /* Create Kernel Program from the source */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&source_str,(const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    /* Build Kernel Program */
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* Create OpenCL Kernel */
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "eval", &ret);
}

void eval_eq () {
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(array1Buffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(array2Buffer);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(array3Buffer);
    array1Buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size * sizeof(double),(void *) array1, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,
                                  array1Buffer,
                                  CL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  size * sizeof(double),
                                  array1,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &event);
    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clReleaseEvent(event);
    array2Buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size * sizeof(double),(void *) array2, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,
                                  array2Buffer,
                                  CL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  size * sizeof(double),
                                  array2,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &event);
    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clReleaseEvent(event);
    array3Buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, size * sizeof(double),(void *) array3, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue,
                                  array3Buffer,
                                  CL_FALSE,
                                  0,
                                  size * sizeof(double),
                                  array3,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &event);
    ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
    clReleaseEvent(event);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&array1Buffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&array2Buffer);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&array3Buffer);
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, array1Buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, size * sizeof(double), array1, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, array2Buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, size * sizeof(double), array2, 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, array3Buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, size * sizeof(double), array3, 0, NULL, NULL);
}


int main () {
    printf("loading kernel..\n");
    create();
    printf("kernel loaded..\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        printf("Step %d..\n", i);
        eval_eq();
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            printf("array1[%d] = %lf\n", j, array1[j]);
            array2[j] = (double) i;
            array3[j] = (double) i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

calc.cl code:

```
void sub_gp (__global double* ar1, __global double* ar2, __global double* ar3, int gpno) {
    ar1[gpno] = ar2[gpno] + ar3[gpno];
}

void gp (__global double* ar1, __global double* ar2, __global double* ar3, int gpno) {
    sub_gp(ar1,ar2,ar3,gpno);
}


__kernel void eval(__global double* ar1, __global double* ar2, __global double* ar3)
{
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    gp(ar1,ar2,ar3,idx);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that 9500 supports double precision?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan i tried some basic samples by passing one array and incrementing them, which works fine. hence i am guessing it is working.

Comment: Check extensions, supported by device. If it doesn't contain cl_khr_fp64, than there is no guarantee, that your videocard can cope with doubles (may be some reduced set of operations in case of vendor-specific extensions)

Comment: i tried using 
#ifdef cl_khr_fp64
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#elif defined(cl_amd_fp64)
    #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_amd_fp64 : enable
#else
    #error "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation."
#endif
............
Actually both graphic cards says: "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation." Is there any other way i can check?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan if both are saying: "Double precision floating point not supported by OpenCL implementation." that means both should not support.  and i am lucky to get results on 1st graphics card. Is it?

Comment: Call clGetDeviceInfo with CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS flag & find cl_khr_fp64 substring. If it's not presented, look at vendor-specific double precision extensions to see what you can get

Comment: Okk.. i printed CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS from both graphics card.. nVidia Corporation GeForce GT 630 (rev a1) showing cl_khr_fp64 flag, but other graphics card 9500 is not showing cl_khr_fp64... this suggets my double datatype will not work on second graphics card. right? Is anything else (limitations) it means @RomanArzumanyan ?

Comment: It means that 9500 doesn't have full double precision support.

Comment: Thanks @RomanArzumanyan that fulfill my answer. But i ran some previous simple codes having double datatype but with very small size of single array. It was able to generate result. There i even don't have any inline function in my cl code. Was i lucky there?

Comment: As I said before, 9500 may support reduced set of operations with doubles because of vendor-specific extensions. Check for that extensions. If they are presented - yes, you was lucky.

Comment: It is clear that the kernel will not work on the GPU without double support. You are ignoring completely the return codes and you don't see the problem popping up. The array has still the same values as you inputted because the kernel did not run at all. In fact, it didn't even compile properly the kernel object.

Comment: I was hoping the same @DarkZeros. how can i come to know that kernel didn't ran? Or it is not compiled properly? double support is the issue, but checking for flag is the only way? kernel compilation throws any error, can't we catch it?

Comment: Check value of ret variable. It contains return code.

Comment: thanks once again @RomanArzumanyan . just wants to add up more. I replaced double everywhere with float. Program runs perfect.

Comment: @Vishwadeep OpenCL is designed as a "possible" feature, so many computer may not have GPU or even a device to use it. The calls to OpenCL will rarely fail or give SEG_FAULTs. The only way to know if they completed is checking the return code. SInce you don't do it, you are not seeing the call to ´clBuildProgram()´ failing. A good practice is to test always the return codes.

Comment: Thanks @DarkZeros i am strictly making this as an habit..

Comment: @DarkZeros i am thinking of one more query... My cl file is too big of around 2-3 MB having lots of equations. On loading return is giving -11 and -46 errors by clBuildProgram and createKernel respectively..  How you suggest to overcome such issues?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan i am thinking of one more query... My cl file is too big of around 2-3 MB having lots of equations. On loading return is giving -11 and -46 errors by clBuildProgram and createKernel respectively.. How you suggest to overcome such issues?

Comment: ERROR -11 = CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE, you should get the log of the build program using getBuildInfo(CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG), which will tell you the compiler errors. But hey! Get a guide and read it, we are answering basic stuff now, which are targeted in any OpenCL Tutorial.